# How to print the stack trace of a caught exception using a one-liner?

Tags: matlab, exception, try-catch, warnings, stack-trace

I want to catch an exception, but print the same message it would print if not caught (stack trace). How to do that?

I tried

```
>> myfunctionwitherror
Error using myfunctionwitherror (line 3)
myerror

>> try myfunctionwitherror; catch disp(lasterror), end
Warning: This try-catch syntax will continue to work in R2007b, but may be illegal or may mean something different in future releases of MATLAB.
See MATLAB R2007a Release Notes, "Warning Generated by try-catch" for details. 
  MException with properties:

    identifier: ''
       message: 'myerror'
         cause: {0×1 cell}
         stack: [0×1 struct]

>> try myfunctionwitherror, catch e getReport(e), end
Warning: This try-catch syntax will continue to work in R2007b, but may be illegal or may mean something different in future releases of MATLAB.
See MATLAB R2007a Release Notes, "Warning Generated by try-catch" for details. 
Undefined function or variable 'e'.
```

How to accomplish this?

---

I am using `2016b`. I don't know why this message appears.

Comment: You are using 2007a, I pressume?

Comment: @AnderBiguri no, see my update

Comment: @SardarUsama I was expecting `e` will take exception object, but this probably does not work in one-liners

Comment: Hi there. Are you still having problems with this? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You are using 2007a syntax for try catch.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2007a/techdoc/index.html?/help/releases/R2007a/techdoc/ref/try.html)

it was:

```
try,
 statementA
catch,
 statementB
end
```

and now is

```
try
 statementA
catch e
 statementB
end
```

But as you are writing one liners, you forgot the `;` so you are just confusing MATLAB about when the lines end, so its assuming you are doing

```
try 
   myfunctionwitherror 
catch 
  e 
  getReport(e)
end
```

Just put the semicolons where they should be when you are using ambiguous one liners. Or write multiple lines. ;)

```
 try; myfunctionwitherror; catch e; getReport(e); end;
```

If what you want is to display the error (without trowing an error) just

```
try; myfunctionwitherror; catch e; disp(e.message); end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the [documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2007a&endrelease=R2007a&category=language-programming#bq24_2g-1) that open when one clicks the link in the warning:

> **Warning Generated by try-catch**
>
> To accommodate future changes in the MATLAB error-handling capabilities, there is a new restriction to the syntax of the `try-catch` block. When the first MATLAB statement that follows the `try` keyword consists of just a single term (e.g., `A` as opposed to `A+B`) occurring on the same line as the `try`, then that statement and the try keyword should be separated by a comma. For example, the line
>
> ```
> try A
> ```
>
> should be written as either
>
> ```
> try, A
> ```
>
> or on two lines as
>
> ```
> try
>    A
> ```
>
> This affects only single-term statements. For example, the following statement continues to be valid:
>
> ```
> try A+B
> ```
>
> The same holds true for the `catch` keyword and a single-term statement following the keyword on the same line. **A valid `try-catch` statement of this type should be composed as follows**:
>
> ```
> try, A, catch, B, end
> ```
>
> If you omit the commas following try and/or catch, your code will continue to operate correctly. However, MATLAB will issue a warning:
>
> ```
> try statements, catch statements, end
>
> Warning: This try-catch syntax will continue to work in R2007a, 
> but may be illegal or may mean something different in future 
> releases of MATLAB.
> ```

#### In conclusion:

```
try, myfunctionwitherror, catch e, disp(e.message), end %#ok<NOCOM>
```

(the `%#ok<NOCOM>` at the end is because a comma after the try generates a lint warning {at least on R2018a}, since it's apparently unnecessary, but w/o the comma we get the runtime warning... go figure)

Comment: Or use semicolons as you generally should :P

Comment: @Ander: why should one generally use semicolons? Semicolons suppress output, commas don’t. If there is no output to suppress, there is no need for a semicolon. Even the official docs use commas to separate `for`, `switch`, `try`, etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I meant when using one liners in fact. Still, 99% of the MATLAB lines one writes do print on command line, I assume one generally wants this not to happen